# Find values in ArrayList with specific conditions

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm trying to create a function that gives a list of arrays and two arrays of integers as input:

```
public boolean[] checkMatching(ArrayList<String[]> items, Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2){...}
```

checks if there are at least two items that have the same values for the indices of **arr1**, but different values for the indices of **arr2**. For example:

```
ArrayList<String[]> items = new ArrayList<String[]>();
//All arrays in items have the same number of elements
items.add(new String[]{"B","2","5","6","W"}); //item1
items.add(new String[]{"A","2","5","6","X"}); //item2
items.add(new String[]{"A","2","1","3","Y"}); //item3
items.add(new String[]{"N","F","1","2","W"}); //item4
items.add(new String[]{"A","2","5","6","V"}); //item5

int[] arr1 = new int[] {1,2};
int[] arr2 = new int[] {0,3,4};

boolean[] results = checkMatching(items, arr1, arr2)
```

In the previous example the function should return:

```
[-1, 1, -1]
```

since **item1**, **item2**, and **item5** share the same values for the indices of **arr1**, while they have different values for indices 0,4, and equal values for index 3.

Notice that, the method returns 3 integers since in **arr2** there are 3 indices. Thus, each boolean refers to an index in **arr2**.

This could be a solution which exploits functional programming:

```
public class Temp2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> items = null;

        items = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        items.add(new String[]{"B","2","5","6","W"}); //item1
        items.add(new String[]{"A","2","5","6","X"}); //item2
        items.add(new String[]{"A","2","1","3","Y"}); //item3
        items.add(new String[]{"N","F","1","2","W"}); //item4
        items.add(new String[]{"A","2","5","6","V"}); //item5
        
        int[] arr1 = new int[] {1,2};
        int[] arr2 = new int[] {0,3,4};

        Temp2 tmp = new Temp2();
        int[] results = tmp.checkMatching(items, arr1, arr2);
        
        for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            System.out.print(results[k]+"|");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int[] checkMatching(ArrayList<String[]> items, int[] arr, int[] arr2){
        int maxIndex = 4;

        Function<String[], String> compositeKey = el -> getFunctionParametersTest(el, arr);

        Optional<int[]> map = items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositeKey, Collectors.toList())).entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() > 1)
                .map(entry -> {
                    List<String[]> values = entry.getValue();
                    int[] generalResponse = new int[maxIndex+1];

                    if (values.size() > 1) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
                            String tmp = "";
                            int risposta = -2;
                            for (String[] e : values) {
                                if(tmp.length() > 0) {
                                    if (tmp.compareTo(e[arr2[i]]) != 0) {
                                        risposta = -1;
                                        break;
                                    } else {
                                        risposta = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    tmp = e[arr2[i]];
                                }
                            }
                            generalResponse[i] = risposta;
                        }
                    }
                    return generalResponse;
                }).reduce((a, b) -> {
                    int[] arrLocal = a;
                    int[] arrarrLocal2 = b;
                    int[] sum = new int[a.length];
                    for (int k = 0; k < arrLocal.length; k++) {
                        if (arrLocal[k] == -1 || arrarrLocal2[k] == -1) {
                            sum[k] = -1;
                        } else if (arrLocal[k] >= arrarrLocal2[k]) {
                            sum[k] = arrLocal[k];
                        } else if (arrLocal[k] < arrarrLocal2[k]) {
                            sum[k] = arrarrLocal2[k];
                        }
                    }
                    return sum;
                });

        int[] finalresults = null;
        if (map.isEmpty() == false) {
            finalresults = map.get();
        } else {
            finalresults = new int[maxIndex+1];
            for (int k = 0; k < maxIndex; k++) {
                finalresults[k] = 1;
            }
        }

        return finalresults;
    }
    
    public String getFunctionParametersTest(String[] item, int[] arr) {
        String values = "";
        for (Integer i : arr) {
            values += item[i] + "-";
        }
        return values;
    }

}
```

But it is not very efficient, especially when there is a large amount of items. Is there anyone who can help me? I am trying to develop a very performing solution and I don't know if there are faster solutions than functional programming.

Comment: What do you mean by returning `[-1, 1, -1]` if boolean array should be returned?  Should it be `[true, true, true]`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko No, it means: [false, true, false]

Comment: Please use `true` and `false` instead of `-1` and `1`. Makes the code much easier to understand. (Yes, I know there is no `BooleanStream`... Use at least `0`/`1`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understand I came out with the following solution. However, I am not sure if any list that matches arr1 is what you would want to compare arr2 with. You might need to change the `findAny()` section in case it is different.

```
public static Boolean[] checkMatching(ArrayList<String[]> items, final int[] arr1, final int[] arr2) {
    // Gets a list containing items that match arr1.
    List<String[]> list = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item ->
            // Groups items together which match in arr1 indexes.
            // Get a stream of indexes contained in arr1.
            Arrays.stream(arr1)
                    // Get a stream of Strings in those indexes.
                    .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(item).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(i))
                    // A list of these Strings is the groupingBy classifier.
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()) 
        )).values().stream().filter(l -> l.size() > 1) // Just get those groups that have more than 1 element.
        .findAny() // Would you want any list that matches arr1?
        .get();

    // Converts arr2 to a Boolean array which says if each index matches all the items in "list".
    Boolean[] matching = Arrays.stream(arr2).mapToObj(i -> list.stream().map(item -> item[i]).distinct().limit(2).count() < 2).toArray(Boolean[]::new);
    return matching;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my implementation:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class Test {
    private static final int LIMIT = 2;
    
    // Implementation ↓
    private static int[] checkMatching(ArrayList<String[]> items,
            int[] keyIndices, int[] valueIndices) {

        Function<String[], String> keyFn = (item) -> Arrays.stream(keyIndices)
                .mapToObj(i -> item[i])
                .collect(joining());

        List<List<String[]>> list = items.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(keyFn, toList())).values().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.size() >= LIMIT)
                .collect(toList());

        return Arrays.stream(valueIndices)
                .map(i -> list.stream()
                        .anyMatch(lists -> lists.stream()
                                .map(item -> item[i])
                                .collect(toSet()).size() == 1) ? 1 : -1)
                .toArray();
    }

    // Test code ↓
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new String[] {"B", "2", "5", "6", "W"});
        items.add(new String[] {"A", "2", "5", "6", "X"});
        items.add(new String[] {"A", "2", "1", "3", "Y"});
        items.add(new String[] {"N", "F", "1", "2", "W"});
        items.add(new String[] {"A", "2", "5", "6", "V"});

        int[] arr1 = new int[] {1, 2};
        int[] arr2 = new int[] {0, 3, 4};
        int[] results = checkMatching(items, arr1, arr2);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
    }
}
```

Which generates the following output:

```
[-1, 1, -1]
```

My approach is as follows:

- build up a map with lists of string arrays for which the indices of `arr1` match;
- filter out the lists that don't have at least two elements;
- map `arr2` to a list of booleans to represent whether all the values are the same for at least one of the entries in the map (using a `Set` to check for distinct values).

The last step is open to optimization. Instead of counting the number of distinct values, you could return early from the moment one different value is found, but it would lead to slightly less elegant and less functional code:

```
return Arrays.stream(valueIndices)
        .map(i -> list.stream()
                .anyMatch(arrays -> {
                    for (int j = 1; j < arrays.size(); j++) {
                        if (!arrays.get(j)[i].equals(arrays.get(j - 1)[i])) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }) ? 1 : -1)
        .toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. However, the timing of your proposal is longer than mine. I think a single pipeline speeds up operations. Below I report the times on the same of our proposals:

Execution time in nanoseconds: 27711000 ns
Execution time in milliseconds: 27 ms
Running time in nanoseconds (my function): 2603700 ns
Execution time in milliseconds )my function): 2 ms

Comment: Yeah, I accept that. Fully functional approaches tend to be slower, unless you can execute in parallel on multiple cores. It should be possible to write a non-functional solution that performs even better, especially if you consider replacing the input with a two-dimensional `char[][]` array.

Comment: I've tightened up my implementation and reduced my execution time by about 40-50%. I don't know how you run your tests, but your code gives me the output `[-1, 1, -1, 0, 0]` and runs about 2 to 3 times slower than my current code in my tests. Do you have a larger dataset you're using for tests? Or is the data format different?